# Appcompat 23.2.1 drawer layout with navigation view covered by status bar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-styles

I switched from the normal Light Dark appcompat themes to DayNight and now the status bar color is being drawn over my window. What changed to break my configuration?

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppThemeDayNight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
    <item name="statusViewStyle">@style/StatusViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeDayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

styles-v21.xml

```
    <style name="AppThemeDayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <!--<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item> -->
    <!--<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item> -->
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>


<style name="AppThemeDayNight.NoActionBar.Drawer">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

activity_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            tools:title="Timeline"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_twitter" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_send" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Here's a screenshot of the drawer open with the navigation view, which should be drawing over the status bar.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

add

```
 <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

to

```
<style name="AppThemeDayNight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

block and try

Comment: There's no change as far as I can tell, after I added it to both styles. I'm testing on API 23 by the way.

Comment: its works for me: <style name="myFullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
    </style>

Answer (score -1):

Try set the windowTranslucentStatus to true

`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`

Comment: please consider android:windowTranslucentStatus = false